# How to design a 4 bit comparator using logic gates?

Tags: systems-design

I'm currently working on a project but I cannot figure out how to make a 4 bit comparator (compare 2 4 bit numbers)
If cascading 1 bit comparators makes it easier then that works too

Comment: This question is probably better suited to SE Electrical Engineering

Comment: Have you considered a 4 bit comparator?

Answer (score 0):

4 XNOR gates connected to a 4-input AND.

XNOR produces 0 on different inputs, 1 on same, so it's a 1-bit comparator. If any of 4 bits differs then the inputs are not equal, and AND will produce 0. If all are equal, you get 1.